# Mute volume smoothly on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpvolumeview

I mean sound should play briefly, then mute.

I have a program for iPad which plays video and I need to smoothly mute volume when pressed and hold "volume down" button on device, or when we exit video while it playing.

Comment: Stack overlfow is meant for code requests, please show some code where you tried solve this yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. iOS devices are programmed to mute volume if the volume down button is held. This is default behavior.